# Installing python packages in nitrousio

Tags: python, package, pip, nitrousio

I've just started trying to use Nitrous.io. I've made a box with python, and am trying to use pip to install a python package called praw.

It downloads all of the information fine, but on running the install script, I get an error stating that it could not create a file due to permission restrictions in the /usr directory. Is there any way to get around this as I need the package for my application to work properly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try `pip install --user praw`

https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#user-installs

Comment: It works well for `pip install --user -r requirements.txt` as well.