# Installing pymongo on a nitrous.io box

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, nitrous

I'm fairly new to Python, and Nitrous.IO, and MongoDB, and command line in general so would appreciate a little guidance here if possible.

I'm trying to install pymongo on my Nitrous.IO box but can't seem to find a way to do it - [this tutorial](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html?_ga=1.238004487.604615506.1413497813) suggests 'import pymongo' but that didn't work (see below).

I can't seem to find any tutorials or help on this - a google search for "install +pymongo with nitrous.io" gave me 0 results.

```
action@thirdyearproject-148753:~(master*)$ import pymongo                                                                                                 
import: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/366.   

action@thirdyearproject-148753:~(master*)$ pip install pymongo                                                                                            
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                        
File "/home/action/.parts/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>                                                                                                 
load_entry_point('pip==1.5.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()                                                                                            
File "/home/action/.parts/packages/python2/2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 356, in load_entry_point                           
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)  
File "/home/action/.parts/packages/python2/2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2431, in load_entry_point                          
return ep.load()                                                                                                                                      
File "/home/action/.parts/packages/python2/2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2147, in load                                      
['__name__'])                                                                                                                                         
File "/home/action/.parts/packages/python2/2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 10, in <modul                   
from pip.util import get_installed_distributions, get_prog                                                                                            
File "/home/action/.parts/packages/python2/2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py", line 15, in <module>                     
from pip.locations import site_packages, running_under_virtualenv, virtualenv_no_global                                                               
File "/home/action/.parts/packages/python2/2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/pip/locations.py", line 96, in <modu                   
build_prefix = _get_build_prefix() 
File "/home/action/.parts/packages/python2/2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/pip/locations.py", line 64, in _get_                   
path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'pip_build_%s' %                                                                                           
File "/home/action/.parts/packages/python2/2.7.6/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 269, in gettempdir                                                    
tempdir = _get_default_tempdir()                                                                                                                      
File "/home/action/.parts/packages/python2/2.7.6/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 212, in _get_default_tempdir                                          
("No usable temporary directory found in %s" % dirlist))                                                                                              
IOError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/home/action']                                                

action@thirdyearproject-148753:~(master*)$ easy_install pymongo                                                                                           
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                        
File "/home/action/.parts/bin/easy_install", line 5, in <module>                                                                                        
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point  
File "/home/action/.parts/packages/python2/2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2829, in <module>                                   
working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()                                                                                                               
File "/home/action/.parts/packages/python2/2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 451, in _build_master                               
return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)                                                                                                      
File "/home/action/.parts/packages/python2/2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 464, in _build_from_requirements                    
dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())                                                                                                                
File "/home/action/.parts/packages/python2/2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 639, in resolve                                     
raise DistributionNotFound(req)                                                                                                                        
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: setuptools==2.2   

action@thirdyearproject-148753:~(master*)$ parts install pymongo                                                                                           
parts: ERROR: Package "pymongo" not found                                                                                                                  
Aborting!
```

Does anyone know how I would go about installing this? It's starting to be a real pain!

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to install it with`pip` using [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992580/installing-python-packages-in-nitrousio). Once you've done that, you would use the `import pymongo` at the top of your code file.